Suspicious access to my Gmail account from "Authorized Application" but I did not permit any third-party apps & services
In the lower right corner of my Gmail page is a link to see my account's access history and activities. In the list, I discovered an entry of access from
"Authorized Application (946277197574-f7mp4v1faacb1ndtpsliojjgcjbv16it.apps.googleusercontent.com)
OAuth Domain Name:
946277197574-f7mp4v1faacb1ndtpsliojjgcjbv16it.apps.googleusercontent.com "
but I did not permit any third-party apps to access my account. I did check my permission on "https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps" there & found it empty. Also change my account password through "Google Security Checkup" and cross checked enable two-step authentication.
Now, How do I find out what has happened with my account?
How do I secure my account privacy & block that unwanted access?

This is likely a mobile app you are logged into.

Looks like entry for accessing via mobile app. You do verify it by 1)Access via desktop and check the entry. 2)Then access via your mobile app and check the entry.
